# Is Windows codepage 936 a superset of both Simplified and Traditional Chinese characters?

Tags: character-encoding

It appears that many Traditional Chinese characters are supported by the Windows implementation of Simplified Chinese character set, which started as GBK / GB2312 and from my understanding now supports the entire GB18030.

The question is, are **all** the Traditional Chinese characters there? If yes, doesn't it make the Big5 character set totally redundant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only a handful of printable non-private-use characters (`¯ˍ‧╴`) present in code page 950 (Big5) but not in 936 (GB2312), none of which are Chinese ideographs.  In that sense, yes, Big5 is “redundant”.

However, for various technical and political reasons, it's highly unlikely that all Traditional Chinese documents will immediately be converted to GB18030 (or UTF-8), so expect Windows to support CP950 for years to come.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please elaborate the technical reasons?